# How do you shut down a Linux system?

Tags: linux, shutdown

Linux seems to have a lot of commands, both for the operating system, as well as Linux tools and utilities, both for GUI and command line use.

I am interested in finding out how to shutdown a Linux system. In addition, I would like to know the varieties and uses for the shutdown command.

I have a tool which works with DOS and is Linux based, so I am assuming there is something that will work for Linux. Otherwise, I cannot complete my work.

Comment: That little red button. or the plug. or a kick. `:-)`

Comment: run `shutdown` from a shell as root.

Comment: What do you mean by code? There is common used program `halt`, usually it sets runlevel to 0 or 6 and shutdowns computer. Also, this site is oriented for programming ;)

Comment: Making me laugh. I have a tool which works with DOS and is Linux based, so until you know codes to command, you can't complete your work.

Comment: How about moving this to server fault?

Comment: @PaicTen Added a major edit, per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 4):

If by code you mean command, here ya go: `shutdown -h now`

However this question has nothing to do with programming and doesn't belong on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this with Ubuntu ever since 8.04

```
sudo halt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the init commands. The most commonly used are:

```
init 0 Halt or shutdown
init 1 Single user mode
init 6 Reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list to the bash commands of linux.
the shutdown command is "shutdown" Shutdown or restart linux

http://ss64.com/bash/